# Job title for someone who inherited a business

Tags: resume, title, business

What job title is appropriate on a resume or on LinkedIn for a person who has inherited a family business, completely owns it, and handles more or less all the day to day operations for it?

*Owner* is an option, but looking for something less obvious.

*Founder* or *Co-Founder* does not fit, as the person did not do that but inherited it.

Comment: What's wrong with "owner"? Why do you want to make it "less obvious"?

Comment: "*the person*" Can we assume you're talking about yourself? Third-person questions can be tedious.

Comment: What actual "job" do you at this company have if you own the company but don't work their you don't have a job title your just the owner.

Comment: I know a few of these and their older employees refer to them as "junior boss".

Comment: What do you mean by "less obvious?"

Comment: Why not CEO?  He does own the business after all.

Answer (score 6):

**Owner** is the only recommended title in such a situation. Especially if you're talking about a small business that only has a few or no employees, anything else will come across as overly pretentious or, worse, misleading. You said that "owner" is obvious, but that's because it's the only title that's truly correct.

**Proprietor** is synonymous on paper but less common and can refer to specific legal entities. I also feel like it's at title that's more often used in the service industry but can't say for sure.

If you're in a partnership, **(Senior) Partner** can also be used.

If you're talking about a company with at least a few employees you could opt for one of these:

- **President**
- **(Managing) Director**
- **General Manager**
- **Business Manager**
- Chief Executive

But all of those hide the fact that you own the company, for no real reason. I'd only opt for these if I wasn't the sole/majority owner or if I had a reason to downplay ownership.

Avoid Chief Executive Officer unless you have a larger company that already has a middle management layer and a C-suite. If you don't have at least a few other CxOs who truly deserve the title, you shouldn't use CEO either.

Similar to Jim's suggestion of "Owner Operator" you can combine owner with pretty much all titles just like you can have the often dreadfully overblown "Founder and CEO". It's typically unnecessary to combine titles unless you're listing the ownership on a resume with other concurrent jobs/roles or when your role changed over time. So if you inherited the company and ran it for a few years but then let someone else take over daily operations you could list "Owner and General Manager" for 20XX-20YY and then just "Owner" for 20YY-20ZZ.

Finally, make sure that you've verified that your title is legally correct. In some countries, like the UK, your title can have legal repercussions depending on how you've structured or incorporated the company.

Comment: Is writing "Owner and General Manager" or "Owner and Business Manager" appropriate?

Comment: @user258699 Yes, that works. It's typically unnecessary to do so unless you're listing the ownership on a resume with  other concurrent jobs/roles or when you moved out of or in to a General Manager role before or after the time you were both Owner and GM. Similar to Jim's suggestion of "Owner Operator" you can combine owner with pretty much all titles just like you can have "Founder and CEO".

Answer (score 4):

Owner Operator works.

Some people can be leery of titles like President and CEO especially for a smaller operation as it's easy to make stuff.

If your business is very customer-facing and you can get away with it you can also invent a 'fun' title like Chief Entertainment Officer, Architect, Head Data Dude, 'I fix plumbing problems within four hours', you get the idea.  One of the benefits of LinkedIn is that you can low-risk experiment a little with the title.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to achieve. On a resume I would stress what I do not what I own.
The "owner" owns the company but not necessarily makes all the business decisions. So "Owner & General Manager" or something similar.

For LinkedIn, Your profile is more a profile of your company. No recruiter is looking for an Owner, so the fancy title doesn't improve your marketability.
Instead potential business partners/customers will check out your profile.
How about just "Boss" on LinkedIn.